# Socket failed to connect while connected using wifi direct

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to make connection between multiple device one act as server or group owner and other as client, which I have implemented using wifi direct and wifi p2p and working fine.

After device connected in a group, i am trying to make socket connection between the server and multiple clients but I can't connect using socket. showing below error

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 8988) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

SockertServer code

```
 @Override
  protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
try {
    server = new ServerSocket(8988);
    Log.d("ServerActivity", "Server: Socket opened");

    Log.d("ServerActivity", server.getLocalPort() + "");

    Log.d("ServerActivity", server.getInetAddress() + "");


    Socket client = server.accept();
    Log.d("ServerActivity", "Server: connection done");

    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
            client.getOutputStream()
    );

    objectOutputStream.writeObject("Hie");

    client.close();
    server.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


return null;
}
```

Client Socket

```
 @Override
          protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
try {
    mSocket = new Socket();

    mSocket.bind(null);
    mSocket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(getAddr, portNo)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

    if (mSocket.isConnected()) {
        Log.d("Client Activity", "Socket Connected Successfully");
    } else {
        Log.d("Client Activity", "Socket not  Connected ");
    }

    ObjectInputStream objectOutputStream = new
            ObjectInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());

    msg = (String) objectOutputStream.readObject();

    message.onMessageSend(msg);
    Log.e(".......................", "Message" + msg);

    objectOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (mSocket != null) {
        if (mSocket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                mSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Give up
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

return msg;
}
```

So anyone can help me out with this problem.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You do not have to call `mSocket.bind(null)`. throw it away and try connecting, also Are you sure the server is still listening? A log would maybe be nice to see for further diagnostic

Answer (score 0):

ECONNREFUSED means that the connection was attempted and the remote host port is not listening. Hence this can be caused because of:

Is it a valid IP? check using ifconfig or ipconfig. you can try pinging the server.

It may also be due to the following reasons:

- -The server couldn't send a response: Ensure that the backend is working properly at IP and port mentioned.
- -SSL connections are being blocked.
- -Request timeout: Change request timeout

Comment: I am using NSD so its give m peers info i.e ip and port number